# Filter dataframe A based on columns from dataframe B

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes where dataframe A has much more columns than dataframe B, what i would like to do is filter dataframe A by using dataframe B as reference and obtain a new dataframe A with the same amount of columns that dataframe A has. For example:

```
df_A = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(150, 17), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMONPQ'))
df_B = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(150, 8), columns=list('ABCDEFGH'))
```

I would like to filter out the extra columns in `df_A` and have a `df_A` with the same columns that `df_B` has.

So `df_A` as output would have columns 'ABCDEFGH'

Comment: ``df_A.loc[:, df_B.columns]``? or to be on the safe side ``df_A.loc[:, df_A.columns.intersection(df_B.columns)]``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use filter.

```
df_A.filter(df_B.columns)
```

Or

```
df_A[df_B.columns]
```